# Empty Spaces in Tokenized Array

Tags: java, file-io

I'm writing a Java program that takes a text file, splits it on white space and `>`, and then manipulates the numbers by means of `Integer.parseInt()` and `Double.parseDouble()`.

However, whenever I try to run my program, I get a `NumberFormatException` because apparently my program is picking up empty spaces for tokens. Below is my code, the text file, and the error.

Code:

```
try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] tokens = line.split(" |>");

            State s = new State(Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]), 0, 
                    Double.parseDouble(tokens[0]), null);
            states.put(s.state, s);

            for(int i = 3; i < tokens.length; i++) {
                if(tokens[i + 2] == null || tokens[i] == "")
                    break;
                else
                    edges.add(new Edge(Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]), 
                        Double.parseDouble(tokens[i + 1])));

                }
        }
        scanner.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.err.println("Error: file could not be found");
}
```

Text file to parse:

```
1 0 > 1 6 2 6 3 6
1 1 > 4 -1
1 2 > 8 -1
1 3 > 9 -1
1 4 > 1 -1 5 -1 6 -1
1 5 > 
1 6 > 7 -1 8 -1
1 7 > 
1 8 > 7 -1
0 9 >
```

Error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at csu.mcdonald.ASrch.main(ASrch.java:33)
```

Comment: can you give the line that cause this error ?

Comment: What is `states` and also how about the class `Edge`? Also `State` appears to be a custom class.

Comment: Sorry. `states` is a `HashMap` containing a list of states I will be using in my program, and `Edge` and `State` are pretty much the same class, just with some different variables.

Comment: The line that gives me the error is `edges.add(new Edge(Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]), 
                        Double.parseDouble(tokens[i + 1])));`

Comment: @mynorka posted my answer, see if it helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the below code with this, should solve your problem.

Output from split is - `[1, 0, , , 1, 6, 2, 6, 3, 6]`

**old code**

```
 if(tokens[i + 2] == null || tokens[i] == ""))
```

**new code**

```
if(tokens[i + 2] == null || tokens[i].equals(""))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to execute your program. I have noticed that getting a string array by splitting the variable 'line' will result in an array

```
[1, 0, , , 1, 6, 2, 6, 3, 6]
```

That is why the line

```
edges.add(new Edge(Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]), 
                        Double.parseDouble(tokens[i + 1])));
```

is throwing an exception.

Here tokens[i] is is an empty string, which will throw a **NumberFormatException**

Please check your logic.

Comment: I've realized that, which is why I posted this question. I'm confused as to why that is happening. Also, I've ran through my program several times, but can't seem to find a reason why that's happening.

Comment: Could you please mention your actual requirement with the class Edge and the logic you want to execute. It will help me to solve your problem